# Can you retrieve messages from instagram or messenger off of a SIM card?

Tags: web-browser

Can you retrieve personal information ie; messages from browsers, off of a SIM card?

Comment: a SIM card is in no way involved in this. Which means you cannot retrieve such messages from the SIM card

Comment: Take a look at what a SIM card is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIM_card#Data

Answer (score 1):

SIM cards contain some form of user identity, location and phone number, network authorization data, personal security keys, contact lists and stored text messages. So, yes, you can retrieve personal information from it. Note that most people do not use the contact list on the SIM card anymore.

The browser does not use the SIM card. So messages from the browser are not stored on the SIM card.